# The XML document has elements which share the same name, but has different data.How can I choose an element with a specifc data? Using a Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, path

```
<object><br>
  <content type="me">myname</content><br>
  <content type="you">yourname</content><br>
  <content type="me">myothername</content><br>
</object>
```

I was trying: `<xsl:value-of select="object/data/@myname"/>`. But it returns all contents. How can I write this Xpath?

Comment: I see no data node and @myname seelcts attribute myname of node data... what you want is probably `"object/content[.='myname']"`

Comment: Maybe I asked it wrong, my real question is how to select elements based on their value? For example, I want the return of the attribute value "me", only if data is myname. 
I tried now `"object[@type="me" and text()="myname"]` but it isn't returning anything

Comment: If you want to select attribute of the node - which you select based on conditions - then first you select node with condition - as I wrote before and then continue to select subnodes or attributes `object/content[.='myname']/@type` - will bring value of attribute type of the node content (under object) which value is myname

Comment: Okay, thank you. It helped a lot! So, if I add another condition that the attribute value must be "me' and the value of the node content must be "myname", would it be correct this path:   `"object/content[@type='me' and text()='myname']`

Comment: looks good. You always can use some online tester to check your xpaths - for example https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html